# SSRS - Report Builder ClickOnce url

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have installed SSRS and it's all working great.  However, when I access the reports from an external URL, the Report Builder uses the internal URL and breaks.

Where would I amend the Report Builder ClickOnce URL so that I can put in the external URL?

Answer (score 1):

You could try changing **Custom Report Builder launch URL** in the Report Manager Site Settings:

[image]

More info at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181194%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

So, for SSRS 2008R2 and Report Builder 3.0, something like

```
http://YourExternalServer/ReportServer/ReportBuilder/ReportBuilder_3_0_0_0.application
```

might work.

You might have any number of permission issues but hopefully this gives you something to try.

Comment: I'll try it out and let you know.